# How to persist date as varchar in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, datetime, jpa, varchar, persist

I have to map my class definition to an existing database where a date field is stored as varchar.

e.g.

```
class A {
    @Column
    Date birth;
}
```

How can I annotate the birth property so that it can be correctly mapped to the database varchar?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The Attribute Converter functionality introduced in JPA 2.1 is exactly for this kind of scenario. If your JPA provider is compliant with the JPA 2.1 spec (for Hibernate I believe this is version >= 4.3) then you can handle as below:

```
class A {
    @Column
    @Convert(converter = DateOfBirthConverter.class)
    private Date dateOfBirth;
}
```

Converter:

```
@Converter
public class DateOfBirthConverter implements AttributeConverter {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Date dateOfBirth) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(dateOfBirth);
    }

    @Override
    public Date convertToEntityAttribute(String dateOfBirth) {
        try{
            return new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(dateOfBirth);
        }
        catch(ParseException ex){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following.

```
class A {
    @Column
    String birth;

    @Transient
    Date dateOfBirth;

    ....
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date date){
        this.dateOfBirth = date;

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        birth = df.format(date);
    }
}
```

**Change the date formatting as you need.**

I think it would be better not to store the date in a varchar because when you retrieve `birth` from database, you have to manually do the date formatting.

You could always change to the following.

```
Class A{
   @Temporal(DATE)
   protected java.util.Date birth;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it works. The database is a legacy one so I can not change its schema. thank!